# spring boot with swagger OAuth not working

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I added swagger dependency and enabled it, and am able to see all the API but authorize API isn't working.

am using below version of swagger:

```xml
    <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is my code :

```java
        @Configuration
        @EnableSwagger2
        public class SwaggerConfig {
            
             @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
            public String CLIENT_ID;
             
             @Value("${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}") 
            public String CLIENT_SECRET;
            
            
            public String AUTH_SERVER = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0";
            
            
            @Bean
            public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
                return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                        .select()
                        //.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()) 
                        //.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/v1/**/**"))
                        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("edu.mayo.ima.ccs.rpc_backend.controller"))
                        .paths(PathSelectors.any()) 
                        .build()
                        .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securityScheme()))
                        .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()))
                        .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
                
            }
            
            @Bean
            public SecurityConfiguration security() {
                return SecurityConfigurationBuilder.builder()
                    .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                    .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .scopeSeparator(" ")
                    .useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant(true)
                    .build();
            }
            
            private SecurityScheme securityScheme() {
                GrantType grantType = new AuthorizationCodeGrantBuilder()
                    .tokenEndpoint(new TokenEndpoint(AUTH_SERVER + "/token", "oauthtoken"))
                    .tokenRequestEndpoint(
                      new TokenRequestEndpoint(AUTH_SERVER + "/authorize", CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
                    .build();
        
                SecurityScheme oauth = new OAuthBuilder().name("spring_oauth")
                    .grantTypes(Arrays.asList(grantType))
                    .scopes(Arrays.asList(scopes()))
                    .build();
                return oauth;
            }
            
            private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
                return new ApiInfo(
                        "Protocol Catalag ",
                        "",
                        "1.0.0",
                        "",
                        null,
                        "",
                        "",
                        Collections.emptyList()
                );
            }
            
            private SecurityContext securityContext() {
                return SecurityContext.builder()
                  .securityReferences(
                    Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("spring_oauth", scopes())))
                  .forPaths(PathSelectors.any())
                  .build();
            }
            
            private AuthorizationScope[] scopes() {
                AuthorizationScope[] scopes = { 
                  new AuthorizationScope("access_as_user", "access for application")
                 };
                return scopes;
            }
    }
```

With the above configuration all Api are showing on the swagger but Authorize them give error.
Below is the screen when Authorize buttton is clicked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Help is Appreciated.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to add the access_as_user permission  under API permissions in the portal and make sure the API is exposed.
Application id uri is in the format api://, you can give other name to use in app.
In the Example here I gave app id uri : api://my_spring_boot_api

[image]

You should then be able to see added scope under scopes.

[image]

Then select the access_as_user permission you have added .(API Permissions>add permission>My APIs > select the required app >check the permission> add permissions)

[image]

Then you may grant consent as below

[image]

[image]

Here I exposed scope >> api://my_spring_boot_api/access_as_user. Make sure to use  the same  scope configured in portal is included in application configuration.
The scope should include the exposing resource's identifier (the Application ID URI) in the code too.

Here Ex:
scopes: "api://my_spring_boot_api/access_as_user "

and when you call web app please make sure to send Id_token and if you call graph **api**  you may send access token.

Comment: after adding the scope with api://<key>/access_as_user, am getting a different error now

Comment: Sign in
Below is the error:
Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.

AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.

Comment: we tried configuring reply address in azure with "http://localhost:9000/api/swagger-ui.html", but that didnt help

Comment: Have you tried giving https:localhost:9000/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html?

Comment: let me try that

Comment: Forgot to keep "//"  in >>  "https://  before local host .Also make sure the redirect uri is same configured in the code too if present.

Comment: i didn't configure any redirect in the code. DO we need to add that somewhere in swaggger config ?

Comment: It's just that the app and azure ad must have same redirect uri(that you can see in web address) .But anyway , can you please try execute now and see what is the outcome?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237966/discussion-between-pradeep-and-kavyasaraboju-mt).